# how to remove ngb-pagination active focus/blur

Tags: css, ng-bootstrap

I'm having trouble figuring out how to remove the focus/blur of the active clicked number. When I click outside of paginator it goes away, but I don't want it to appear at all when I click a button. I can't  find the correct CSS style to get rid of the border blur/focus.
I'm using ngb-pagination.  I appreciate any help!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Override page-link:focus class as below

```
.page-link:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it didn't work. The blurred outline still appears when focused.

Comment: This style should be in a global css file and not css file inside your component. If you can share you code on some online angular editor, I maybe able to assist more

Comment: That seemed to work, but it's still not perfect. It has this light blue outline https://postimg.cc/bGRV0kNN    If I try with ```border-style:none``` I get https://postimg.cc/G4CjMtfB and if I try with ```border-color:(same color as background color) then it looks like first image https://postimg.cc/bGRV0kNN

Comment: Have you tried `border-color: transparent !important;` ?

Comment: @Andy try with `border-width: 0`

Comment: border-width: 0 didn't work. Same light blue outline showing

Comment: Please put some reproducible code on slackblitz  or sandbox as I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your global styles file:

```
ngb-pagination::ng-deep .page-link:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following code: Now it doesn't show any outline.

```
/deep/ .pagination .page-item .page-link {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  color:black;
}

/deep/ .pagination .page-link {
  border-top-style: none !important;
  border-bottom-style: none !important;
  border-left-style: none !important;
  border-right-style: none !important;

}
```